# how to convert flash buttons into html button in datatables stackoverflow

Tags: datatables

```
$('#example').DataTable( {
        dom: 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
        "bPaginate": false,
        "bSort" : false,
        "bFilter": false, 
        tableTools: {
            "aButtons": [

                {
                    "sExtends": "xls",
                    "sButtonText": "Download Excel",
                     "sTitle": '<?php echo $name['first_name'].'-'.$name['last_name'].'-'.$name['id'];?>',
                    "oSelectorOpts": {
                        page: 'current'
                    }
                },
                {
                    "sExtends": "pdf",
                    "sButtonText": "Download PDF",
                     "sTitle": '<?php echo $name['first_name'].'-'.$name['last_name'].'-'.$name['id'];?>',
                    "sPdfOrientation": "landscape",
                    "sPdfMessage": "<?php echo $name['first_name'].' '.$name['last_name'].' PreApp 1003 Application Details'; ?>"
                },
                 {
                    "sExtends": "mae",
                    "sButtonText": "Download in Fannie-Mae",
                    "sTitle": '<?php echo $name['first_name'].'-'.$name['last_name'].'-'.$name['id'];?>',
                    "sPdfOrientation": "landscape",

                }
            ]
        }
    } );
```

Comment: Thank you for including code, but can you specify the source of your problem? (Is an error being thrown, does it not work as expected, etc.)

Comment: i want to create  mae button   which generate .fnm  file

Answer (score 1):

`TableTools` extension doesn't support `HTML5` version of that functionality https://datatables.net/extensions/tabletools/. And since it is now retired, don't expect this functionality to be available.

However, `TableTools` were converted into another extension `Buttons` https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/, which supports both `HTML5` and `SWF` versions.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#table').DataTable( {
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
            'copyHtml5',
            'excelHtml5',
            'pdfHtml5'
        ]
    } );
} );
```

See more examples here https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/html5/index.html

Comment: Thanks  Andrei Zhytkevich !         I just  tried this code it worked fine , But I also Want to add one more button of  extension .fnm  . Unfortunately  by This  code it could not be possible to create .fnm button , it seems is that this version of datatables does not support to create .fnm button

Comment: Looks like `fnm` is not a button from the standard set of buttons in `TableTools`. I see another one `mae` in your example. You have to figure out what are they and probably re-implement (or just copy) the functionality in the new `Buttons` extension. P.S. If the example in my code works fine, please consider upvoting and accepting my answer.